# MongoDB atlas, connection not working

Tags: java, mongodb

I just created a free MongoDB atlas cluster instance. But somehow I am failing to connect it from my application as well as from the MongoDB Compas.

I get below error when I try to run my application.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=experimental-1-epdri.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: experimental-1-epdri.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: experimental-1-epdri.mongodb.net}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:377) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:104) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:411) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:71) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:845) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:828) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:491) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndex(MongoCollectionImpl.java:458) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.axonframework.mongo.eventsourcing.eventstore.AbstractMongoEventStorageStrategy.ensureIndexes(AbstractMongoEventStorageStrategy.java:201) ~[axon-mongo-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.axonframework.mongo.eventsourcing.eventstore.MongoEventStorageEngine.ensureIndexes(MongoEventStorageEngine.java:123) ~[axon-mongo-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 76 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

On Compas it simply says MongoDB instance isn't running at this place. I have checked my cluster and I see below.

[image: Seems like it is up..]

But still I can't connect to mongo cluster. Further more I tried with `Mongo CLI as well where I found error as shown below.
[image: Error while connecting using CLI.]

Below is the connection string that I get from the MongoDB atlas page.

`mongodb+srv://admin_eventdb:<PASSWORD>@experimental-1-epdri.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`

Please help solve this.

Comment: What is the version of you MongoDB Compass?

Comment: I am using 1.14.6 version of Compass

Answer (score 2):

Please try with:

```
Hostname: experimental-1-epdri.mongodb.net
SRV Record: checked
Authentication: Username / Password
Username: admin_eventdb
Password: <PASSWORD>
Authentication Database: admin
Replica Set Name:
Read Preference: Primary
SSL: System CA / Atlas Deployment
SSL Tunnel: None
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51042704/8370915). Via connection string using Java Driver 3.4 it would be:

```
mongodb://user:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Instead of `<PASSWORD>` I wrote own password. `admin1`is my admin-user.
[image]

---

**Updated:** if you want to use drivers `3.7+`, you need to write instead of format connection (and to avoid my issues above)

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://admin:mypassword@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

another variant using `MongoClients.create()` [(as of the 3.7 release),](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/):

```
   MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://admin:mypassword@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
```

**Note:** the password need to write not like `mongodb://user:<mypassword>@...`, just in format `mongodb://user:mypassword@...` without braces `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
I point I mentioned

Please login to mongodb atlas
1.go to security section
2.network access
Then allow anywhere access that it's may be helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

**for Node.js** : checkout [Atlas MongoDB connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971993/atlas-mongodb-connection/61997396#61997396)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const conStr = 'mongodb+srv://lord:<password>@cluster5-eeev8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

const DB = conStr.replace(
  '<password>',
  myPass
);

const DB = conStr.replace(
  'test',
  myDatabaseName
);
//remember mongoose.connect() return promise
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    usedNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((con) => {
    console.log(con.connection);
    console.log('DB connection successful');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to use Atlas.  This is the configuration that worked for me with Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: sample_training 
      uri: mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@cluster0-hosturl.aws|gcp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```