# Atlas MongoDB connection

Tags: node.js, express, mern, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to Atlas MongoDB with the following URI (provided by mongodb connection string )

```
    module.exports = {
        mongoURI:'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-un6sk.mongodb.net/test? 
    retryWrites=true'
    };

    //connect to mongoose
    mongoose
        .connect(db)
        .then( ()=>console.log('mongoDB connected'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**I get the following error :**

```
{ MongoNetworkError: connection 3 to cluster0-shard-00-00-un6sk.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KARTIT Ismail\Desktop\devconnector\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:352:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at _handle.close (net.js:606:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Please hide your connection url for safety.

Comment: opps! I edited it. it's just for a prototype though , thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have whitelisted your IP in the Atlas Control panel.

You can enter `0.0.0.0`, if you wish to allow access from any host.

[image]

Then you can have a connection string like below:

```
var connectionString= 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<clustername>/<dbname>?ssl=true&replicaSet=<replica setname>&authSource=admin';

var db = mongoose.connect(connectionString).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: I used your solution by allowing access from any host and it worked! Thank You Sir

Answer (score 2):

Whitelist the IP address, the best option allows access from any host, I believe everyone had installed mongoose, if not then use this command

```
npm i mongoose
```

First copy your application connection string from mongodb.com -> clusters->connect->connect your application

Now chose driver Node.js and version latest, now copy connection string.

Now connection.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const conStr = 'mongodb+srv://lord:<password>@cluster5-eeev8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

const DB = conStr.replace(
  '<password>',
  myPass
);

const DB = conStr.replace(
  'test',
  myDatabaseName
);
//remember mongoose.connect() return promise
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    usedNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((con) => {
    console.log(con.connection);
    console.log('DB connection successful');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to Atlas MongoDB you should configure IP whitelist. Go to MongoDB Atlas website, login. Then, from the Clusters view, select the Security tab, then IP Whitelist. You will see an IP address. Click "Edit" Button then "current IP address". Press OK. Then restart your server.

Useful link : https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#add-whitelist-entries

Answer (score 0):

What version of mongoose are you using? Versions of mongoose less than version 5.0.15 doesn't appear to support the `mongodb+srv://` server url.

The other common issue, is white listed IP addresses.

Source:
[Error at connecting to MongoDb Atlas Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894913/error-at-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-server)

Answer (score -3):

Just whitelist the IP from the Atlas UI no need to restart the application.